# CSS - Position an element relative to a table

Tags: html, css

This is the UI I would like to make:
[image: screenshot from figma]

But when I right align the drop-down, it sticks to the end of the page:
[image: screenshot of the webpage]

This is the code of the table header:

```html
<div class="d-flex align-items-center mt-5 table-header">
                <img src="images/Logs Icon.png" alt="Logs icon" class="folder-icon">
                <p class="table-title d-inline">Your current logs</p>
                <div class="dropdown">
                    <a class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" id="navbarDarkDropdownMenuLink" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                      All
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-dark" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink">
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item disabled" href="#">All</a></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Mini glass</a></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Glass</a></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Bottle</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
```

This is the CSS that is causing the issue:

```
.table-header {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr repeat(3, auto) 1fr;
    grid-column-gap: 5px;
    justify-items: center;
}

.table-header :nth-child(1) { grid-column-start: 2; }
.table-header :nth-child(3) { margin-left: auto; }
```

Thanks for looking through my code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use flexbox? And make sure that the header is the same width as the table.

```
.table-header {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks for contributing to SO. I did try the above, but the problem is that the width of the table is unset, which is why they have different widths. Is there something that I can do to ensure that the widths are the same?

Comment: Put the header and the table in the same wrapper and the wrapper will be the width of the table. Then set the header to 100% width of the wrapper?

Comment: Thanks a lot! Setting  ```width: fit-content``` to the wrapper solved the problem